# Aligning image with respective tables using materializecss

Tags: html, css

Find full code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxErrR

I am trying to display different tables and its respective images. Below is the screenshot for actual requirement. This is the requirement.

[image: One]

**And this is how far I have progressed.**

[image: Two]

**Note:** I am using materializecss and would be nice to achieve this using the same.

```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="featuresanimate">
       <div id="features" class="section scrollspy">
         <div class="container">
           <h2 style="text-decoration:underline;text-align:center;font-  weight:bold;font-family:Comic Sans MS">Features</h2><br><br>
             <div class="features">
               <table style="width:100%">
                 <tr>
                   <img src="images/d.png" height="100" width="100">
                   <th >one</th>
                   <img src="images/a.png" height="100" width="100">
                   <th >two</th>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                   <td >profile</td>
                   <td >profile</td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                   <td>profile</td>
                   <td>profile</td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                   <td>profile</td>
                   <td>profile</td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                  <td>profile</td>
                  <td>profile</td>
                 </tr>

                </table>          
             </div> 
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I hope now it has been narrowed down to what I require and so remove it from hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) CSS framework. I would ditch the tables-for-layout approach and use the [grid system](http://materializecss.com/grid.html) provided by the framework. See a [working Codepen demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQmOgm).

```css
h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0d47a1;
}

img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.feature-set {
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 115px);
}

ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="featuresanimate">
    <div id="features" class="section scrollspy">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 style="text-decoration:underline;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-family:Comic Sans MS">Features</h2>
        <div class="features">
          <div class="col s6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100" width="100">
            <div class="feature-set">
              <h3>One</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>profile</li>
              <li>profile</li>
              <li>profile</li>
              <li>profile</li>
            </ul>
            </div>            
          </div>
          <div class="col s6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100" width="100">
            <div class="feature-set">
              <h3>Two</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>profile</li>
              <li>profile</li>
              <li>profile</li>
              <li>profile</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right. I am using materializecss. Grid system is so powerful. It worked great. Thank you anyways. Can you explain me what does this do-  width: calc(100% - 115px);

Comment: calc() is a CSS function, because we want `.feature-set` to float and take up all remaining space in the fluid-width parent container we subtract the known width (of the image + 15px margin) from 100%.

Comment: Ok. And if I want to make this a responsive then how would I do that?

Comment: Well it is to a point, but modify the image/feature-set to use the grid and [media](http://materializecss.com/media-css.html) patterns from materializecss instead. Take the time to read the docs ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could put them in seperate `div`s

Unless you need to use tables for some reason?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeVjgL

Comment: you have errors in your codepen. please fix them.

Comment: Hey I was able to achieve using your answer as well But I accepted Karl's answer because of grid system. Thank you anyways. So just upvoted your answer. Cheers

Comment: @Lal Can you tell what are the erros in his answer as It worked for me.